# Elasticsearch / Rails Tire autocomplete with multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

I have the following index in Elasticsearch within a Rails model:

```
  mapping do
    indexes :id,                                type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :number,                            type: "string"
    indexes :title,                             type: "string"
    indexes :description,                       type: "string"
    indexes :creation_date,                     type: "date",     index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :photographer,                      type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :photographer_name,                 type: "string",   as: Proc.new { photographer.name if photographer }
    indexes :original_type,                     type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :original_type_description,         type: "string",   as: Proc.new { original_type.description if original_type }
    indexes :format_type,                       type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :format_type_description,           type: "string",   as: Proc.new { format_type.description if format_type }
    indexes :country,                           type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :country_name,                      type: "string",   as: Proc.new { country.name if country }
    indexes :state,                             type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :state_name,                        type: "string",   as: Proc.new { state.name if state }
    indexes :state_region,                      type: "string",   as: Proc.new { state.region if state }
    indexes :locality,                          type: "string"
    indexes :license_type,                      type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :license_type_description,          type: "string",   as: Proc.new { license_type.description if license_type }
    indexes :model_release_type,                type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :model_release_type_description,    type: "string",   as: Proc.new { model_release_type.description if model_release_type }
    indexes :property_release_type,             type: "integer",  index: :not_analyzed, include_in_all: false
    indexes :property_release_type_description, type: "string",   as: Proc.new { property_release_type.description if property_release_type }
    indexes :keywords,                          type: "string",   as: Proc.new { keywords.map(&:value) }
  end
```

I need to implement an `autocomplete` field and found a lot of material, including here, teaching how to do this using `Elasticsearch` and Tire. However, they all show suggestions based on only one field in the index.

I need the `autocomplete` field suggest terms found in several fields, for example title, photographer and keywords. Furthermore, the field keywords is an array, ie contains several words.